# How do I initialize the fitbit Fitgem client in config/initializers?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4, fitbit

#### For convention reasons I would like to initialize the Fitgem client in config/initializers/fitgem.rb.  When I say initialize I mean pass in my app's consumer token and consumer secret like so:

```
Fitgem.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "XXXX"
  config.consumer_secret     = "XXXX"
  config.token               = "XXXX"
  config.secret              = "XXXX"
end
```

This is the exact same manner that is done with Facebook and Twitter clients (https://github.com/sferik/twitter) elsewhere.  Is there a similar way I can do this with Fitgem?

### The error I receive when I try to initialize the client this way is:

***undefined method `configure' for Fitgem:Module***

The fitgem docs (http://www.rubydoc.info/github/whazzmaster/fitgem/frames) say to do it like this:

```
client = Fitgem::Client.new {
  :consumer_key => my_key,
  :consumer_secret => my_secret,
  :token => fitbit_oauth_token,
  :secret => fitbit_oauth_secret
}
```

But I don't want to have to re-initialize the Fitgem client in every method.

#### So, number 1, I would love to know how to do this, and number 2 I would love to know how to look at the fitgem code to see that configure is not an acceptable method.

Comment: I found [this](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/mygem-configure-block) explanation from ThoughtBot, which should help me go through the Fitgem and sferik/twitter code to figure out what's going on and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's been out of date to answer, but now there is [omniouth for fitbit](https://github.com/tkgospodinov/omniauth-fitbit). It's not so difficult to use the gem because there is the explanation about how to do the configuration. You have to make `omniauth.rb` file under config/initializers and place the consumer_key and consumer_secret there.